# How to solve 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'items' in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am running a python code in Pycharm and i used Pytorch for training. but i get this error

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'items'
```

also my code is like this:

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl 
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=5, gpus=0, reload_dataloaders_every_epoch=True,
                 progress_bar_refresh_rate=50, logger=False, 

checkpoint_callback=False)

trainer.fit(model)
```

also this is the link of the full code that I'm trying to run
[Movie Recommender Systems Using Neural Network](https://www.kaggle.com/code/mejbahahammad/movie-recommender-systems-using-neural-network)

Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Please post a [mre] (what exactly is `pl` and where does it come from?).

Comment: I'm assuming `pl` refers to pytorch-lightning but there isn't much we can do to help you without looking at your `LightningModule`

Comment: @desertnaut it refers to pytroch-lightening import pytorch_lightning as pl

Comment: @RayanHatout how can i share this module with you ?

Comment: This should be explicitly included in your question, instead of leaving people assuming - please edit to add the relevant import

Comment: @atf.sgf You still haven't including your `LightningModule` with that edit, please include the class that `model` is an instance of. We have no way of telling what's wrong otherwise.

Comment: @RayanHatout you can check the full code from the link that I attached to my question

Comment: Man the code you linked is nothing like what you posted, try to format better your code because this seems an easy to solve issue so we could help. On the other hand, check that what your dataloader is returning is a dict and not a Tensor